# How to pass parameter from widget to activity when I click on widget

Tags: android, android-widget

How to pass parameter to activity from widget from screen ? I have widget on screen and code like this

```
            Intent defineIntent2 = new Intent(context, LOG.class);
            defineIntent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            defineIntent2.putExtra("id", id);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent
                    .getActivity(context, 0 /* no requestCode */,
                            defineIntent2, 0 /* no flags */);
            remoteViews
                    .setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget, pendingIntent2);
```

but when I click on widget and enter at LOG activity and try to read that parameter I have passed ( id)

```
int id = getIntent().getIntExtra("id",
                -1);
```

I always get -1. How to pass parameter from widget to activity ?

Comment: What is the code that sets id?

Answer (score 3):

Intents are reused in Android. If you want the changes you make deliver correctly, you can use  FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT FLAG:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent
                .getActivity(context, ,
                        defineIntent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```